# How to create codeigniter routes dynamically?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-routing

I have a CI *routes.php* as below.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['404_override'] = 'site';
$route['admin'] = 'admin';
$route[':any'] = 'site/user';
```

The thing required is when any user name (which I will check with database) is typed with URL like - `localhost/CIproj/username` then it should go to `site/user` controller.

If 'admin' is there in URL like - `localhost/CIproj/admin` it will go to `admin` controller (index function). URL will change to `localhost/CIproj/admin/dashboard`.

So the error I am getting is when I go to `localhost/CIproj/admin`, I get login screen. But after login it will go to `admin/dashboard`. This is where I get redirected to `site/user`.

Then I tried with below one.

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = 'site/user';
```

And now everything was working. But the URL will be like - `localhost/CIproj/user/username`.

So the question is , is there any way where I don't have to write `user` in the URL. Visitors can type anything in the URL.

```
 localhost/CIproj/anything
```

if `anything== username from database` it will go to `site/user`.

if `anything== admin or any of its page` it will go to respective controllers.

Or else *404pagenotfound.php*.

Note: Admin is a huge module with many controllers. So I don't think I should write routes for every of admin controller here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sitting blank. Gone through the question again and found the solution.
So the question is , is there any way where I don't have to write user in the URL. Visitors can type anything in the URL.

localhost/CIproj/anything

if `anything== username from database` it will go to `site/user`.

if `anything== admin or any of its page` it will go to respective admin controllers.

Or else `404pagenotfound.php`.

The route.php will be like this ->

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";  // controller - site / method - index (404 page).  
$route['404_override'] = 'site';  // same as above
$route['(iam:any)'] = 'site/user/$1'; // appending 'iam' to anything user enters. then in 'site' controller and 'user' method I will remove 'iam' from the segment and then check with database username. if found it will proceed to respective user page or else 404 page.
```

Answer (score 2):

For site user you can use something like:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'site/user/$1';
```

Here you will get $1 as a parameter for username and your URL will look like:

```
localhost/CIproj/anything
```

Comment: I think you didnot get the question. Here as you suggested surely I will get users, but admin part I can not get. As it will always redirect to `site/user/` if admin logs in and the URL changes to `admin/dashboard`.

Comment: In the controller where you check for the username parameter, you can put an additional check that if username == admin than redirect it to admin/dashboard

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I load my routes https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Dreamhost-.htaccess

```
$route['step_1'] = "install/step_1/index";
$route['step_2'] = "install/step_2/index";
$route['step_3'] = "install/step_3/index";
$route['step_4'] = "install/step_4/index";
```